# Is "to pass away" used for non-humans?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is it OK to use pass away for an animal/pet, or it is just for human?

If it doesn't sound OK, what should be used instead, died?

Comment: Okay in whose opinion? Yes, some of us may say their pet passed away. And others of us will inadvertently roll our eyes upon hearing it.

Comment: @choster I mean, to Native American English speakers. In general in USA. Who roll the eyes upon hearing it?

Comment: It's used for persons.  If non-human animals are regarded as persons, then "passed" is appropriate.  It's not just for family pets -- I've heard it used for the great race horse Secretariat, e.g..

Comment: Just so long as it isn't used for the star of a cute cat video, I see no reason to object.

Comment: When in doubt and if sensitivity is called for, it can always be said that an animal (even the one from the cute cat video) has crossed over the "Rainbow Bridge".  There's a website and even a touching little poem to help comfort the surviving humans: https://rainbowsbridge.com/Poem.htm

Comment: But only animals?  I don't say: the 8-inch floppy disk passed away in the 90's.

Comment: @GEdgar - It didn't pass away, it just migrated to The Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

[Pass away](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pass+away) means:

> 1. To pass out of existence; end.
> 2. To die.

[TheFreeDictionary.com]

Actually "pass away" is an euphemistic phrase to mean "die" as it doesn't sound respectful to the dead and it could be unpleasant (for some people) to hear.

[*Euphemism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism) means:

> a mild or pleasant word or phrase that is used instead of one that is
>   unpleasant or offensive.

You can use "pass away" for human beings and animals that have passed out of existence. If you google it, you will see a lot of examples used for animals like dogs and cats.

Comment: Thanks. I don't google it since I don't know who answers. I want to ask it from Native American English speakers.

Comment: @Susan I understand. But you can at least see how they are being used in a certain context. You need to use "of" in place of "from" in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok for animals too. For some people dogs especially are family members.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As StackExchange seeks *definitive* answers, rather than personal opinions, your submission would be strengthened with an expansion; for instance, citing examples of its use in major publications, or noted writers, would affirm its validity among the literati. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.